# Inflating ImageButton programatically changes width & height params to wrap_content. Why?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate, layoutparams

In my app I'm using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

Left half of the toolbar always acts as back button.

Right half is different for different activities. Sometimes it's just text, sometimes a button. So I inflate the right half with views programmatically.

**Toolbar**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
...
... <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_LL"/>
...
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_LL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I'm inflating this view in right_LL:

**child_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/right_IB"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:src="@drawable/save"
android:background="@null"
android:onClick="onRightHeaderButton"
android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

I'm adding it programatically like this:

```
right_LL.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_button,
                    null, false));
```

So **the problem is** that the button occupies half the screen. It's original dimensions are 512x512.

I thought that maybe the LayoutParams are somehow getting reset, so I also tried

```
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) (30 * scale + 0.5f);

right_IB = (ImageButton) right_LL.findViewById(R.id.right_IB);
right_IB.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    pixels,pixels));
```

it gave this exception:

j`ava.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_button, null, false)`, you are passing in `null` for the parent view - this causes any `layout_` attributes to be ignored (as those attributes are only used by the parent view) - see [this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/Hepj6KynZD5) for more details.

Instead, you should use

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_button, right_LL, true));
```

This causes your `child_button` layout to be inflated properly for its parent layout, `right_LL`, and automatically added (that's what the `true` does).

Comment: Didn't work. I did this.
right_LL.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_button,right_LL, true));

Comment: When you use `inflate(id, parent, true)` the `true` is automatically calling `addView()` for you - you just need exactly the line I included in my answer and nothing more.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I have also posted an answer. Can you please read that & add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just by chance I decided to surround my ImageButton with a LinearLayout & it worked!!!
So the issue is resolved.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/right_IB"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="onRightHeaderButton"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't really know why, but it did. If someone can give me proper explanation for that I'll be great.

Comment: Same thing: when you don't include a parent in your `inflate()` call, then the outermost `layout_` attributes are ignored - however, now your `ImageButton` actually has a parent layout and hence, its `layout_` attributes are retained.